# Skype is saying I am already connected. I am not. Help?

Tags: 12.04, skype

Can you help me? I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Skype is saying I am already connected but I am not. What can I do?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to open a second instance of skype. If so, please first close it down. If the application doesn't seem to appear run "killall skype" in a terminal (without quotation marks) in order to terminate the previous skype instance. If you are using Unity, I suggest you to keep the skype icon sticky on the panel and DON'T close it. Simply minimize and you won't lose the running instance of skype. Please inform if you succeed in order to place this as an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I still cannot get it to work :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Finally I removed my local Skype configuration and I am online. So:

1. close all your running Skype instances (probably only 1)
2. remove directory $HOME/.Skype/
3. start Skype